# Instance method 'save(_:where:completion:)' requires that 'PostModel' conform to 'Model'

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, datastore

I am attempting to integrate AWS Amplify DataStore into my Swift application. However I keep on getting this error Instance method 'save(_:where:completion:)' requires that 'PostModel' conform to 'Model'. What does this mean?

```
import Foundation
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins

protocol PostingAmplify {
    func addPost()
}

extension PostingAmplify {
    func addPost() {
        let post = PostModel(username: "champ", text: "pog", mediaLink: "pog", year: 1, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 1, minute: 1, second: 1)
        
        Amplify.DataStore.save(
            post
        ) {
            switch $0 {
            case .success:
                print("Added post")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error adding post - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instance method 'save(_:where:completion:)' requires that 'PostModel' conform to 'Model'

This is Post Model by the way

```
import Foundation

struct PostModel: Decodable {
    var username: String
    var text: String
    var mediaLink: String
    var year: Int
    var month: Int
    var day: Int
    var hour: Int
    var minute: Int
    var second: Int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make `PostModel` conform to `Model` protocol

```
struct PostModel: Model, Decodable { // add the conformance
    // add the protocol requirements...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, however when I add Model it just says Cannot find type 'Model' in scope

Comment: Try importing the dependencies. `import Amplify` or other whichever works.

Comment: Amplify plugins don't have the model dependency

Comment: Here's what you need to do: Check the definition of `save` method. Look for the parameter type the method is asking for see if your `PostModel` satisfy the requirement to be the parameter of `save` method.